# C++: How can I create a number of members of a class depending on the input from the user?

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to make a simple multiplayer game in C++, which needs to be able to have a variable number of players. I thought I could handle this by creating a class with the 'score' values for each player and then each player would be a separate member of the class.

```
int main(void)
{

 int input_players;

 cout << "Welcome to Pig" << endl;
 cout << "Please enter the number of players: ";
 cin >> input_players;

 int *playersarray = new int[input_players];

 for (int i = 1; i <= input_players; ++i)
 {
    playersarray[i] = i;
    //scores playersarray[i];
    cout << playersarray[i] << endl;
 }

 system("PAUSE");
}

class scores
{
 public:
     int last_roll;
     int turn_total;
     int total_score;
};
```

In the for loop, you can see my problem where I am trying to create the number of players by creating different members of the class where the line has been commented out. As I do not know how many players will be playing each time, I cannot declare the members as normal. for example:

```
scores player1
scores player2
scores player3
```

Is there anyway I can create the number of members depending on number input by the user?

Comment: same as you did with `playersarray`: use an array (or `std::vector`)

Comment: yep. you should use vectors if you don't want to worry about memory lifetime

Comment: Basically, you need to create an array of `scores` of size `input_players`. Also arrays start from `0` and not `1`. Valid indexes of an array of size `n` are from `0` to `n-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a `Player` class (after all, you're dealing with "players" :-), and then using a size variable container (e.g., `std::vector`) to hold your players.

Something like this:

```
class Scores
{
public:
    int last_roll;
    int turn_total;
    int total_score;
};

class Player
{
public:
    Scores scores;
    ...
};

int main(void)
{
    cout << "Welcome to Pig" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the number of players: ";

    int input_players;
    cin >> input_players;

    std::vector< Player > players;

    for (int i = 0; i < input_players; ++i)
    {
        // insert in players vector a new Player with scores
        // last_roll=1, turn_total=2, total_score=3
        players.push_back( Player{ Scores{ 1, 2, 3 } } );
        ...
        // print the total_score of i-th player:
        cout << players[i].scores.total_score;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the line

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the line                                                           players.push_back( Player{ Scores{ 1, 2, 3 } } );                                              Doesn't this line assume I already have the scores for each player? I need to create a vector of the players first and then have a way to access them and assign scores to each player after the player list has been created

Comment: I'm also confused with the class for Players, in particular the line that reads 'Scores scores'

Comment: @ElliotPage to assign scores after you create the vector you do: `players[i].scores.total_scores=42;`

Comment: @ElliotPage `Scores scores;` declares an object of type `Scores` called `scores`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the built-in array, you can use a `std::vector` and just `push_back` score instances for all players, which you then access by index. Alternatively you can also use a `std::map`/`std::unordered_map`, if you want to access the scores by player name. These data-structures handle memory-management for you too.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a separate array of type score so the declaration would look as `Scores players[input_players]` and than init them in a loop.

Comment: You do not advice to use Variable Length Arrays in C++, do you?

Comment: No i would use dynamic memory allocation but Elliot has used it in this way so i kind of went with the flow

Answer (score 0):

I think that your loop is wrong because the array's index begins with 0.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer and post some code snippet for better understanding.